# Device to device communication with Xamarin

Tags: sockets, xamarin, bluetooth, cross-platform

I am developing an application for iOS, Android, UWP and Windows Phone 8.1 device with **Xamarin Forms**.

In this app I have a key feature witch require the app to send notifications to other device (which are also running the app).
The amout of data is realy low but it has to be fast (don't want to use a backend).

**What I want to do:**

- When the user lunch the app, the app scan network (Wifi and/or bluethooth) to find if another app is already running)
- If the app find nothing, it launch a server part.
- If the app find someting, it connect to the other device (with allow/disallow screen).

So I am considering the **folowing solution** :

- Wifi (but it requires all devices to be on the same network).
- Bluetooth

I don't find best pratice or guides for this.
Does someone have already tried and have a solution ?

Thanks.